# Duplicating multi-language entry

Tags: localization, entry, bug

How can I duplicate an existing multi-language entry with all the translated content?

When I choose 'Save as new items' when editing an entry, only the content in the language I selected is copied to the new entry. All the translations are lost.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

**Update:**

I don't know much about the inner workings of Craft, but from the http request of the action 'Save as a new entry' I can see that the entryId field is overridden by an empty value. This makes me believe that this action does not really duplicates the entry with all it's translations, but simply add's a new entry with the content of the old entry in the language from which you are viewing the entry.

Is this correct? If so, I guess I have to make a special plugin that adds an option to duplicate an entry with all it's translations.

Comment: Are the other languages turned on for that section?

Comment: Yes, two languages are turned on for the section. The content of the entry I'm want to duplicate is translated in both languages. In the settings on the fields the option 'This field is translatable' is checked.

Comment: I believe a plugin would be needed to accomplish this.